# MVC 4 \ cshtml compile location

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, razor

Just to make sure I get the architecture right:

MVC 4 (with its razor and cshtml stuff) compiles the HTML page in SERVER side and hand it over to client browser, right?

As opposed to, for example, Ext JS, which the browser download Java script that generates HTML in the CLIENT side, and fetch data on its own from some server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep, all MVC view pages are loaded by the code and compiled,  This is done in order to process things like Razor, Models etc.

Ext JS   is a javascript library that has the ability to create Html Elements client side, The only interaction with server side that libraries like Ext JS have is Posting of data ( form data, Json, XML ) and the fetching of data ( Xml, Json, Html )

These are two totally different things, When you visit an MVC Site  on say:

www.domain.com/home

You are essentially making a call to Controller Home, Action Index.   This loads the View Index.cshtml,   Processes any template information ( such as razor ), renders the Html and returns Html content ( with no code ).

Ext Js  is detecting a client side action, and processing this action on client side, and dealing with everything in a asynchronous manner.